# question related about axios post method in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**I am creating a form in which multiple fields are there we are using axios to post the data  but at the time of the post method all the data is saved in payload but it is not showing in the Console , only I'd storing in database.

```
 const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject1, setSelectedSubject1] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject2, setSelectedSubject2] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject3, setSelectedSubject3] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject4, setSelectedSubject4] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject5, setSelectedSubject5] = useState("");
  const [selectedSubject6, setSelectedSubject6] = useState("");
  const [selectedCourse1, setSelectedCourse1] = useState("");
  const [selectedCourse2, setSelectedCourse2] = useState("");
  const [selectedCourse3, setSelectedCourse3] = useState("");
  const [selectedCourse4, setSelectedCourse4] = useState("");
  const [installmentInput1, setInstallmentInput1] = useState("");
  const [installmentDate1, setInstallmentDate1] = useState("");
  const [installmentInput2, setInstallmentInput2] = useState("");
  const [installmentDate2, setInstallmentDate2] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");


  const handleImage = (e) => {
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(e.target.files);
  };
  

  const handleSubmitData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(phone);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", image);
    formData.append("name", name);
    formData.append("phone", phone);
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("subject1", selectedSubject1);
    formData.append("subject2", selectedSubject2);
    formData.append("subject3", selectedSubject3);
    formData.append("subject4", selectedSubject4);
    formData.append("subject5", selectedSubject5);
    formData.append("subject6", selectedSubject6);
    formData.append("course1", selectedCourse1);
    formData.append("course2", selectedCourse2);
    formData.append("course3", selectedCourse3);
    formData.append("course4", selectedCourse4);
    formData.append("installmentInput1", installmentInput1);
    formData.append("installment1Date1", installmentDate1);
    formData.append("installmentInput2", installmentInput2);
    formData.append("installment1Date2", installmentDate2);
    formData.append("address", address);


    

    
    console.log("FormData:", formData);
    // Replace 'YOUR_API_ENDPOINT' with your actual API endpoint
    axios
      .post("/admission", formData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Form data sent successfully:", res);
         console.log(formData);
       
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending form data:", error);
      });
  };
```

As you can see, I have posted the data from my form using the Axios POST method. The console is indicating a status of 200, and the payload is also displaying the values from the form correctly. However, when I attempt to print the value of formData in the console, it doesn't appear, and only the ID is being stored in the database.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Which console log is not printing? is the response coming back as expected? If the data is not getting persisted in the DB then can it be your server issue?
Did you check if the request is correctly reaching the BE? If the request is properly reaching BE then the client code should not be an issue.

Please specify more details.